# What are CPU time, user time, system time respectively?

Tags: linux, cpu, time

I find someone asked a similar question, but my problem is NOT `user-cpu-time`, but `user time` vs `system time` vs `cpu time`. For example, the following info is what I got after a simulation on Linux:

```
User Time        = 199:06:48:50
```

`System Time      = 08:16:57`

`Wallclock Time   = 6:05:56:40`

`CPU              = 199:15:05:48`

`Max vmem         = 26.111G`

`Exit Status      = 0`

I do know what `wallclock` is and I just provide everything as a reference.

I'm clear about what `system-CPU-time` and `user-CPU-time` stand for, but in my case, these two split into `cpu time`, `system time` and `user time`. Then I don't know what each of them exactly means.

The system is openSUSE and I used the 32 cores of the whole 120.

Comment: What operating system?  Yes;  I see the tag but I originally missed it since it wasn't in the question itself.

Comment: How many CPU cores do you have on that system?

Comment: @Rowland Shaw: there are 120 cores and I use 32 of them.

Comment: @Ramhound: it's Linux or more specificly, it's openSUSE.

Comment: You should provide that information in the question.  Like I said I missed it because it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

I would've guessed at 32 cores, as the CPU time is more or less exactly 32 times the wallclock time.

The system time and the user time sum to form this figure, and effectively are broken down as time doing kernel operations, and your application code (and the non-kernel portion of what it's calling).

Comment: You mean `system+cpu=user`; `wall*32=user`? Maybe you're right, but in that case `either` of `system` and cpu is responsible for the so-called application code, then such nomenclature is a little bit wired.

Comment: I'm saying: `user + system = cpu = wall * cores`

Comment: Year, I got it wrong, this seems more reasonable. Thanks;).